# Como colocar bordas nas imagens usando html5+css?

Tags: css, html5

O código desenvolvido até agr fracionado esta aqui se precisarem do codigo completo estará no pastebin

HTML: https://pastebin.com/9k1Xd9MC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Glass</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="interface">
    
<figure class="foto-legenda">
<img src="_imagens/glass-quadro-homem-mulher.jpg">
<figcaption>
    <h1>Google Glass</h1>
    <h2>Uma nova maneira de ver o mundo!</h2>
</figcaption>
</figure>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:https://pastebin.com/KBKiK2df

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
        color: black;
        }

    p {
        text-align: justify;
        text-indent: 50px;
       }
       


figure.foto-legenda { 
border: 8px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha tinha dois erros de sintax no seu código. Primeiro que a tag para imagem é `<img>` e não `<image>` e a sua tag `<figure>` estava escrita errado... *figuTe*

Tirando isso se vc quer a borda só nas imagens vc deve usar um seletor que selecione todas as img, tipo assim `.class img { borda }`

Para entender melhor veja o código abaixo com as correções.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
    color: black;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 50px;
}

figure.foto-legenda img {  /* seleciona todas as img dentro de figure com a classe foto-legenda */
    border: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="interface">

<figure class="foto-legenda">
<img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
<figcaption>
    <h1>Google Glass</h1>
    <h2>Uma nova maneira de ver o mundo!</h2>
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples, para colocar bordas em imagens você pode utilizar a propriedade CSS `border`. Para isso precisaremos definir o tamanho da borda, o tipo e a cor da mesma.

No exemplo abaixo definimos uma borda de 4px, com estilo sólida e com a cor `#000`, preto.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/table-with-fuzzy-background_1253-28.jpg">
```

**Referências:**

- [Guia completo sobre o css border](https://www.devmedia.com.br/css3-border-trabalhando-com-bordas-em-css3/28923)
- [Border MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)